# Is there a way to install msm directly without creating another setup?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I would like to know if there is a way to install msm directly without creating another setup project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. MSM packages have the purpose of sharing resources, for example VC++ redistributable, that you can include in the installer of your application, like prerequisites.

Also, they are used by companies which develop multiple applications that run on the same core resources, thus allowing them to avoid creating two separate packages in which half of the resources are identical, and also when a change is done in the core, it gets automatically propagated to all the teams that use the MSM file.